# Aligning 3 equations with cases and equation number

Tags: equations, align

in the equations shown below I would like to have the 'if' texts aligned - right now this does not work due to the use of three independent array environments. Thanks!!
[image: three equations with cases]

Here is the code to generate above shown equations:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:RawOffsetCalculation}
y_\text{offset raw}
&
=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0
&
\quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\
\\
\dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{raw}}{n_\text{offset}}
&
\quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
\end{array}
\right. \\
\label{eq:CorrectedOffsetCalculation}
y_\text{offset corr}
&
=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0
&
\quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\
\\
\dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{corr}}{n_\text{offset}}
&
\quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
\end{array}
\right.
\\
\label{eq:CumulativeOffsetCalculation}
y_\text{offset cum}
&
=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0
&
\quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\
\\
\dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{corr cum}}{n_\text{offset}}
&
\quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Wolf277, Out of theme: You could use `cases` math environment for equations with cases.

Comment: Your summation notation is a bit idiosyncratic: The summation index is set to `i`, yet the variables being summed do not seem to contain an `i`-component.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `p` column specifier instead of r:

```
\begin{array}{>{\RaggedLeft$}p{6em}<{$}l}
```

It needs the `$ ..$` definition because its contents is in text mode:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align}\label{eq:RawOffsetCalculation}
    y_\text{offset raw} & =\left\{
        \begin{array}{>{\RaggedLeft$}p{6em}<{$}l}
            0 & \quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\[\normalbaselineskip]
    \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{raw}}{n_\text{offset}} & \quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
    \end{array} \right. \\
    \label{eq:CorrectedOffsetCalculation}
    y_\text{offset corr}
    &
    =\left\{ \begin{array}{>{\RaggedLeft$}p{6em}<{$}l}
      0 & \quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\[\normalbaselineskip]
    \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{corr}}{n_\text{offset}} & \quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
    \end{array} \right.
    \\
    \label{eq:CumulativeOffsetCalculation}
    y_\text{offset cum} & =\left\{
    \begin{array}{>{\RaggedLeft$}p{6em}<{$}l}
      0 & \quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\[\normalbaselineskip]
    \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{corr cum}}{n_\text{offset}} & \quad\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
    \end{array} \right.
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: having more space between the intra-`\cases` lines than between the `\cases` entries makes them look like the last part of the first `\cases` is closely associated with the first part of the second one.  a mixed message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cases` environment for this kind of equations. For your problem You could define `multicases` envinment and use `phantom` command to get correct alignment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
 \newenvironment{multicases}[1]
   {\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
    \array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
   {\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \begin{align}
 y_\text{offset raw}&=
 \begin{multicases}{1}
  0,& \text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\
  \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{raw\phantom{ cum}}}{n_\text{offset}},&\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
 \end{multicases}\label{eq1}\\
 y_\text{offset corr}&=
 \begin{multicases}{1}
 0,&\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\
 \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{corr\phantom{ cum}}}{n_\text{offset}},&\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
 \end{multicases}\label{eq2}\\
 y_\text{offset cum}&=
 \begin{multicases}{1}
 0,&\text{if }n_\text{offset}=0 \\
 \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^{n_\text{offset}}y_\text{corr cum}}{n_\text{offset}},&\text{if }n_\text{offset}>0
 \end{multicases}\label{eq3}
 \end{align}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Note `label` is after each equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that keeps your basic `align`/`array` setup. The desired alignment is achieved by (a) measuring the width of the largest fractional term and (b) placing the 0-terms in boxes of said width.

I would further like to suggest that you (i) insert a bit of whitespace between the three equations and (ii) indicate explicitly the dependence of the terms being summed on some index variable `i`. (In the code you've posted, `i` occurs below the summation signs but nowhere else.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" environment

% define the largest fractional term and save its width to "\mywid"
\newcommand\bigfrac{%
  \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_{\text{offset}}} y_{\text{corr\,cum},i}}{n_{\text{offset}}}}
\newlength\mywid
\settowidth\mywid{$\bigfrac$}  % save width of "\bigfrac" to "\mywid"

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{equation}{13}
\begin{align}
y_\text{offset\,raw} &=\left\{
\begin{array}{r@{\qquad}l}
   \makebox[\mywid][r]{$0$} %% place "0" in a box of width \mywid
   & \text{if $n_{\text{offset}}=0$} \\[1.5ex]
   \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_{\text{offset}}}y_{\text{raw},i}}{n_{\text{offset}}}
   &\text{if $n_{\text{offset}}>0$}
\end{array}\right. \label{eq:RawOffsetCalculation}\\[3ex]
y_\text{offset\,corr} &=\left\{
\begin{array}{r@{\qquad}l}
   \makebox[\mywid][r]{$0$} %% place "0" in a box of width \mywid
   & \text{if $n_{\text{offset}}=0$} \\[1.5ex]
   \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_{\text{offset}}}y_{\text{corr},i}}{n_{\text{offset}}}
   & \text{if $n_{\text{offset}}>0$}
\end{array}\right. \label{eq:CorrectedOffsetCalculation}\\[3ex]
y_\text{offset\,cum} &=\left\{
\begin{array}{r@{\qquad}l}
   0 %% no special treatment needed for this term
   & \text{if $n_{\text{offset}}=0$} \\[1.5ex]
   \bigfrac  % re-use the macro (no need to type it in again, right?)
   & \text{if $n_{\text{offset}}>0$}
\end{array}\right. \label{eq:CumulativeOffsetCalculation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```